# ngLocale with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

Has anyone successfully integrated `ngLocale` with webpack in a truly dynamic matter? I am trying to only load the Angular locale that my app currently needs, but webpack includes all possible locales in one big chunk.

What I am trying is:

```
(function(config) {
    'use strict';

    var angularLocale = config.angularLocale;

    require.ensure(['angular'], function(require) {
        require('angular-i18n/angular-locale_' + angularLocale + '.js');
    });
})(require('config'));
```

but preventing webpack from generating one huge chunk with all locales in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [bundle loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader).
Just require your angular locale file like this:

```
require('angular-i18n/angular-locale_' + angularLocale + '.js');
```

and then add this to your webpack config loader rules:

```
{
    include:  path.join(bowerDirectory, 'angular-i18n'),
    use: [{
                loader: 'bundle-loader',
                query: {
                    lazy:true,
                    name: '[name]'


                }
            }]
}
```

This will generate bundle chunks. One for each angular locale.